# how can get fileDate using base64 to string in vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, base64

how can get fileDate using base64 to string in vue.js?

I found this methods, but I could not use this code because I did not why it was not go to reader.onload = (function (theFile)

```
function uploadFileChunk(fileData, uploadInfo, destinationDirectory) {
  var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = (function (theFile) {
                  return function (e) {
                    var binaryData = e.target.result;
                    var base64String = window.btoa(binaryData);
                    theFile.base64 = base64String;
                  };
                });
}
```

but I hope I could do modify like this one

```
function uploadFileChunk(fileData, uploadInfo, destinationDirectory) {
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = fileData;   // file source 
                    var binaryData = fileData;
                    var base64String = window.btoa(binaryData);
                    fileData.base64 = base64String;
}
```

if I using above code, I will get this base64 code

```
base64: "W29iamVjdCBGaWxlXQ=="
```

this is fault, so how could I do?

or if I want to use this methods, how could I get base64_recode values?

If when the user wants to upload a file, the function uploadFileChunk will be triggered at the beginning, when I get the fileData through function uploadFileChunk, then throw the fileData to the function handleFileSelect, and finally get the base64_recode, then how do I return the base64_recode to the function uploadFileChunk for use ?

```
function uploadFileChunk(fileData, uploadInfo, destinationDirectory) {

console.log(fileData);
```

I will get this infotmation

```
File {name: "2.PNG", lastModified: 1626051361706, lastModifiedDate: Mon Jul 12 2021 08:56:01 GMT+0800, webkitRelativePath: "", size: 39337, …}
lastModified: 1626051361706
lastModifiedDate: Mon Jul 12 2021 08:56:01 GMT+0800  {}
name: "2.PNG"
size: 39337
type: "image/png"
webkitRelativePath: ""
__proto__: File
```

may I convent this information to base64 ? if I can do it, how do I do?

Comment: @Bravo I updated the new context.

Comment: @Bravo I updated my context, can you check out please?

Comment: no idea what you're doing any more - code is unreadable, you still haven't stated what problem you are having with code I said would work